# WSO2 Create API and deploy published through API Manager

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have installed WSO2 EI and WSO2 API Manager and create a REST API in Eclipse wso2 developer studio and create local server and redeploy it and when i am login through serverip:9443/carbon it is showing my APIs and working fine now what i need i do not want to deploy here finally i want to published it through API Manager.

I need help how to do that

My API Manager is running on serverip:9446/carbon

Answer (score 0):

you start with reading [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/50518330)  (RTFM)

basically - log into the API Publisher https://serverip:9446/publisher and create an API

Comment: i need to create api from esb as i need to do some transformation or etc

Comment: @EngineerKhan you have to do that manually, log in into the API Publisher amd follow the documentation.

Comment: right now i am using MULE ESB create ESB flows over that and create a zip and upload it in the Mule API Manager to publish the API and implement policies etc now i need the same scenario to be used in wso2.

Comment: @EngineerKhan yes, you may expect it.. You have to design the APIs manually in the API Publisher. (it is possible then export/import designed APIs frough Publisher's APIs later, but that's not so straightforward either). It may be misleading, but APIs in ESB (any REST service) are different from APIs from API Manager, you cannot just import the definition from ESB